# Weird angular 2 behavior

Tags: angular

I am puzzled by the following situation: I have a component myComponent which contains a component called GoogleMapsAutocompleteComponent.

the child component has an output called placeChanged. In the template of myComponent I have:

```
{{test}}
<google-maps-autocomplete (placeChanged)="placeChanged()"></google-maps-autocomplete>
```

In the typescript file of my component I initialize the test property and I define the placeChanged method

```
test : string = "not fired"   

placeChanged(){
    console.log("fired");
    this.test = "fired";
}
```

When the placeChanged event is fired, "fired" gets logged on the console immediately, but it takes very long to update {{test}} on the screen. (Sometimes up to 10 seconds). However if I click on my component after the event is fired, but before {{test}} is updated on the screen, it gets updated immediately.

What is happening here? It seems like angular doesn't notice the change. Is there a way to notify angular that the test property has changed?

Comment: I have no clue why the change isn't detected immediately, but you should be able to use NgZone's run method to reflect the change immediately.  Also, are you seeing issues like this in other parts of your app?  Did you change the ChangeDetectionStrategy by chance?

Comment: Using NgZone solves the problem, thanks! I have not experienced this behavior before in other parts of the app, and I did not mess with the ChangeDetection Strategy. I have next to no experience with this zone / changedetection stuff, but I think maybe it has to do with the fact that the event comes (indirectly) from the google.maps API.